# Structure declaration

Tags: c

I have seen structure declarations which looks like this one

```
typedef struct br {
        int year;
        int km;

} Car;
```

I know that I can use that structure like

```
Car ford;
ford.year = 1980;
ford.km = 12
```

But for what "br" stands in the declaration ?

Comment: there are so many copies of this Q it would be hard to list them all.
These are basics, read *any* tutorial (best case C standard) and you will find answer to this. Why upvotes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`br` is called the structure tag.

The new type created is `struct br` and `Car` is just a type alias for `struct br`.

This declaration

```
struct br ford;
```

is equivalent to this declaration:

```
Car ford;   // ford is of type struct br
```

Also the combo form:

```
typedef struct br {
    int year;
    int km;
} Car;
```

is equivalent to these declarations:

```
struct br {
    int year;
    int km;
};

typedef struct br Car;
```

Comment: So I can omit br, right ? I mean it is legal to use such a declaration typedef struct {... } Car;

Comment: @foho yes, in the combo form the structure tag is not required

Comment: You really need the structure tag if you want a car pointer inside the struct. You can't define `Car *p` inside it, because `Car` isn't defined yet, but you can define `struct br *p`.

Answer (score 5):

This is a combined *declaration of `struct`* and a *type definition*. `Car` is te name of a newly defined type; `br` is the *structure tag*. You can use it as follows:

```
struct br x;
```

This combined declaration is equivalent to the following two declarations:

```
struct br {
    int year;
    int km;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct br Car;
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `struct br{...};` you actually define a new type `struct br;`. Then you typedef this new type into a new type `Car`. The actual type is `struct br`. So `br` is just a placeholder for the *structure tag* in this case (since you don't use it).

Answer (score 0):

`br` is the structure tag (or "name") of the structure. Read the typedef as "`typedef` the `struct`ure called `br`, which I'm declaring to contain `int year` and `int km`, to be also known as `Car`"

Answer (score 0):

The thing here is that you are defining a `struct br` and then you are using `typedef` to use `struct br` with the alias `Car`.

So basically:

```
struct br ford;
```

is the same that

```
Car ford;
```

Take a look at the typedef [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x7sfztk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Look at typedef syntax:

> typedef "type" "name";

struct br {...} is what you "name" by typedef.

Part of programmers (lil me and Linus Torvalds for example) believe that typedefs in hands of beginners are deus ex machina of code.

I follow rule: "**use typedefs when you are hiding something**", many'd disagree though.

> struct linked_list_element *head;

is prolly more clear than:

> list *head;

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers given:

The struct tag is a superfluous feature if you are using typedef.

There is only one use for a struct tag together with typedef, and that is when the struct needs to reference itself. For example, a node in a linked list can be declared as:

```
typedef struct node
{
  struct node* next;
  int data;

} Node_t;
```

The `next` pointer will now point to structs of the type `Node_t`.

Answer (score 0):

In your question shown below

```
typedef struct br {
        int year;
        int km;

} Car;
```

That there are br representing structure tag and Car is showing type definitions.
    You can also rewrite the code in following order.

```
struct br
{
        int year;
        int km;

} ;
typedef struct br Car;
```